# Align environment end {align*} error

Tags: errors, align, statistics, underscore

I have an issue to run the following code in an align environment:

```
\begin{align*}
&\mathrm{
    E(Y_i|D_i=1)-E(Y_i|D_i=0)&=E(Y_{1i}|D_i=1)-E(Y_{0i}|D_i=0)
    }\\
    \mathrm{
    &=\underbrace{E(Y_{1i}|D_i=1)-E(Y_{0i}|D_i=1)}_{\text{ATT}}+\underbrace{E(Y_{0i}|D_i=1)-E(Y_{0i}|D_i=0)}_{\text{selection bias}}
    }.
\end{align*}
```

The error message shows me the following:
!Missing } inserted.\end {align}

I have tried to debug the code myself, however, all debug attempts were unsuccessful.

Can anyone figure out where the mistake is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you put `&` inside the `\mathrm{}`, it will cause that error.
I modified your code a little bit (move the `&` out of `\mathrm{}` and add some spaces with `\:`).

```
\begin{align*}
&\mathrm{
    E(Y_i|D_i=1)-E(Y_i|D_i=0)}\\
    =\:&\mathrm{E(Y_{1i}|D_i=1)-E(Y_{0i}|D_i=0)
    }\\
    =\:&\mathrm{\underbrace{E(Y_{1i}|D_i=1)-E(Y_{0i}|D_i=1)}_{\text{ATT}}+\underbrace{E(Y_{0i}|D_i=1)-E(Y_{0i}|D_i=0)}_{\text{selection bias}}
    }.
\end{align*}
```

Here is the result:
[image]

For the last line to get normal text too, you can try this

```
\begin{align*}
&\mathrm{
    E(Y_i|D_i=1)-E(Y_i|D_i=0)}\\
    =\:&\mathrm{E(Y_{1i}|D_i=1)-E(Y_{0i}|D_i=0)
    }\\
    =\:&\underbrace{\mathrm{E(Y_{1i}|D_i=1)-E(Y_{0i}|D_i=1)}}_{\text{ATT}}+\underbrace{\mathrm{E(Y_{0i}|D_i=1)-E(Y_{0i}|D_i=0)}}_{\text{selection bias}}.
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I was just looking for. But how can I solve the issue that the last line is still italic?

Comment: You can add `\mathrm` to each `underbrace`. You can see the edit in my post.

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to print math upright, use a dedicated package rather than adding unwanted markup such as `\mathrm`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathastext}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
& E(Y_i|D_i=1)-E(Y_i|D_i=0)
\\
&=E(Y_{1i}|D_i=1)-E(Y_{0i}|D_i=0)
\\
&=\underbrace{E(Y_{1i}|D_i=1)-E(Y_{0i}|D_i=1)}_{\text{ATT}}
 +\underbrace{E(Y_{0i}|D_i=1)-E(Y_{0i}|D_i=0)}_{\text{selection bias}}.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, in this case is it important to write `|` or `\mid`?

Comment: @Sebastiano I'd use `\mid`, or, at least, `\,|\,` But the OP seems not to be worried about correct appearance of math…

Answer (score 3):

Welcome! This is due to the `mathrm{…}` commands containing an ampersand. Anyway, with `align*`, the equation does not fit the text width, so I suggest using  `multline*`. I also replaced the various `|` with `\mid`, which has a better spacing, and added a small vertical spacing between the two lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
    \mathrm{E(Y_i\mid D_i=1)-E(Y_i\mid D_i=0) =E(Y_{1i}\mid D_i=1)-E(Y_{0i}\mid D_i=0)}
   \\[0.8ex]
=\underbrace{\mathrm{E(Y_{1i}\mid D_i = 1) - E(Y_{0i}\mid D_i=1)}}_{\text{ATT}} + \underbrace{\mathrm{E(Y_{0i}\mid D_i=1)-E(Y_{0i}\mid D_i=}0)}_{\text{selection bias}}.
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

[image]